# Traefik max-conn

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

We are using traefik for ingress and was wondering if there are any configuration to limit the maximum number of concurrent connection. When using Apache or nginx or even haproxy, I always configures the max number of concurrent connections . For nginx, i use the worker_connections. Is there any concept like this on traefik. I could find some middleware for limiting the infligh request https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/inflightreq/. But i am looking for some config to prevent the backend by bombarding a lot of request.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this help: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/#maximum-connections

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response. This seems to be the one i was looking.